# CMake find_package() cannot find include dirs

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to install two projects: Foo and NeedsFoo.  I have successfully compiled and locally installed Foo using cmake.  However, I'm on a server and cmake doesn't appear to "remember" where Foo is.

In the cmake to configure NeedsFoo I have

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "<prefix>/foo-install/CMake/FOO") # add path to FOOConfig.cmake
find_package(FOO REQUIRED)
if( FOO_FOUND )
   MESSAGE(STATUS "Found FOO!")
endif( FOO_FOUND )

MESSAGE(STATUS ${FOO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

"Found Foo!" is printed --- so cmake finds FOO --- but the variable `${FOO_INCLUDE_DIRS}` is empty and, therefore, the package does not compile.  Any thoughts?

EDIT: There seems to be another copy of Foo installed on the server.  Unfortunately, I can't use it (it is the 'master' branch of our project and I need to use my own branch).  I tried changing the find_package call to

```
find_package(FOO REQUIRED PATHS "<prefix>/foo-install/CMake/Foo" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` affects on *module* mode for `find_package`: It is used for finding `FindFoo.cmake`. That is why your first approach doesn't work. But your second approach should work. Did your tried clean configuration(with empty build directory)? What cache entry `Foo_DIR` contains after such build? (cached variables are listed in `CMakeCache.txt`).

Comment: The second approach with a clean build worked ... not sure why

Comment: The thing is that variables `Foo_FOUND`, `Foo_DIR` and some others *are cached*. So second running `find_package()` doesn't renew them. It is common thing with CMake - if something doesn't work as expected, then **clean build directory and rerun cmake**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the headers are installed, often you'll need to install a -dev or -devel package to get the headers. If they are installed and you can see them in your system, they might be on a path that cmake isn't expecting. Open the findFoo.cmake file (on Linux this will generally be in /usr/share/c make-x.y/modules) and check the list of expected locations, see if you're have installed in a less conventional one.

Comment: There doesn't seemto be a "FindFoo.cmake" file in /usr/share/cmake-x.y/modules --- although there are plenty of other "Find*.cmake" corresponding to other programs (Matlab, MPI, Git, ect...)

Comment: Can you tell me what Foo actually is in your scenario?