# How to use Mujoco in CMake project?

Tags: cmake, find-package

I have installed Mujoco into `/opt/mujoco`.

When I built a project that depends on `Mujoco`, I made the following changes in the `CMakeList.txt`:

```
set(MUJOCO_FOLDER /opt/mujoco/lib/cmake)
find_package(mujoco 2.3.7 REQUIRED PATHS ${MUJOCO_FOLDER} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
if (mujoco_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Find mujoco:  ${mujoco_INCLUDE_DIRS}, ${mujoco_LIBRARIES}")
endif()
```

Mujoco can be found and the message is also printed in the terminal, but variables `${mujoco_INCLUDE_DIRS}` and `${mujoco_LIBRARIES}` are empty.

I have removed the `build` folder and rerun the `cmake` command many times, but the above vars are still empty.

Besides, I checked the `CMakeCache.txt` following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532530/cmake-find-package-cannot-find-include-dirs), and `MUJOCO_DIR:PATH` correctly points to the desired path.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mujoco generates a [config file package, not a find-module package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#using-packages).

As such, it won't set any variables as part of the `find_package` call but instead provide an imported target for your executable to depend on:

```cmake
set(MUJOCO_FOLDER /opt/mujoco/lib/cmake)
find_package(mujoco 2.3.7 REQUIRED PATHS ${MUJOCO_FOLDER} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

add_executable(my_app)
# ...
target_link_libraries(my_app PUBLIC mujoco::mujoco)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer which helps me a lot. But I have one last question, which I hope you can answer. Do you know Robot Operating System (ROS)? Some binary packages can be found by `find_package()`, and the corresponding `${XXX_INCLUDE_DIRS}` and `${XXX_LIBRARIES}` are not empty. These ROS libs are also config file packages. After reading the link you provided, I think the key reason for my question is that there are no sentences like `set(Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PREFIX}/include/foo-1.2)` and `set(Foo_LIBRARIES ${PREFIX}/lib/foo-1.2/libfoo.a)` in the `mujocoConfig.cmake` file. Am I right?

Comment: @KKKmelody That is correct. In the end it is up to the project itself to determine in what form and under which names it exports its data from the config file. So you cannot tell beforehand without checking the documentation or the CMake sources for the respective project.